# internet explorer FileReader result is null for big files

Tags: file, null, upload

In internet explorer, when I'm trying to upload bigger video files (70MB), the FileReader.onload this.result (in my code: event.target['result']) is null.

```
reader.onload = function (event) {
      if (event && event.target) {
        if (event.target['result']) {
          that._file.id = that.id;
          that._file.src = uploadedFile.file;
          that.attachmentForm.controls['fileName'].patchValue(
            uploadedFile.file.name
          );
          that._file.description = uploadedFile.file.name;
          that._file.fileType = uploadedFile.file.type;
          that._file.deleteFlag = false;
          that._file.fileExtension = that.getExtensionFromFileName(
            uploadedFile.file.name
          );
          that.fileUploaded.emit(that._file);
        } else {
          that.error_message = FileUploadErrors.file_corrupted;
        }
      }
    };

    if (uploadedFile.file) {
      reader.readAsDataURL(uploadedFile.file);
    }
```

When I try to upload files around 30MB, it works OK. Windows is able to play all the videos. Chrome, firefox is working great with this code. any ideas, where is the problem?

[debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G67LK.jpg)

[result null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpvXg.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It is because IE does not fully support the file reader. For IE the file load needs to be done in split parts, each not more than 20MB big.